# imagepng($image);captcha and session variables

Tags: php, session, variables, captcha

I have the following code:

```
<?php session_name('mysession');
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test Captcha</title>
</head>

<body>

Captcha Image:
<img src="get_captcha.php" width="139" height="139" />
<?php 
echo 'Captcha text:'.$_SESSION['random_number']
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

and get_captcha.php is:

```
<?php
session_name('mysession');
session_start();
$string = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $string .= chr(rand(97, 122));
}

$_SESSION['random_number'] = $string;

$dir = 'fonts/';

$image = imagecreatetruecolor(165, 50);

// random number 1 or 2
$num = rand(1,2);
if($num==1)
{
    $font = "Capture it 2.ttf"; // font style
}
else
{
    $font = "Molot.otf";// font style
}

// random number 1 or 2
$num2 = rand(1,2);
if($num2==1)
{
    $color = imagecolorallocate($image, 113, 193, 217);// color
}
else
{
    $color = imagecolorallocate($image, 163, 197, 82);// color
}

$white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255); // background color white
imagefilledrectangle($image,0,0,399,99,$white);

imagettftext ($image, 30, 0, 10, 40, $color, $dir.$font, $_SESSION['random_number']);


imagepng($image);

?>
```

The problem is that when I run first time the test-captcha.php I get the following error:
Undefined index: random_number in test-captcha.php on line 17 ($_SESSION['random_number'] is not set!!!!)

After refreshing the page the $_SESSION['random_number'] displays the previous captcha text!
Does anybody have any ideas why this happens??????

Comment: try to set $_SESSION in with random numbers test-captcha.php not in get_captcha.php

Comment: same problem here :) , i searched many about this solution but no way

Answer (score 0):

Because of first time session have empty.
so first time you have to set any value to session.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['random_number']))
{
    echo 'Captcha text:'.$_SESSION['random_number']
}
else{
    $_SESSION['random_number']='any data';   
}
?>
```

Something like that you want.

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

> $string = '';
>
> for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
>
> ```
> $string .= chr(rand(97, 122));
> ```
>
> }
>
> $_SESSION['random_number'] = $string;

Write this code in your html page not in get_captcha.php. It works fine.